# cassandra 2.2.8 cluster timeout exceptions

Tags: cassandra

I have a 3 node cluster with low load. Any write/read attempts to Cassandra are getting timed out. The 'nodetool status' shows every thing up, however, 'nodetool describecluster' shows the other nodes as UNREACHABLE (not because of schema mismatch, because I don't see any schema mentioned next to the unreachable nodes.)

```
# nodetool describecluster
Cluster Information:
        Name: ------
        Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
        Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
        Schema versions:
                8b7c6bca-f4f8-3d49-a4cc-64ec69bf8573: [10.65.221.36]

                UNREACHABLE: [10.65.221.20, 10.65.221.4]
```

cqlsh command is also timing out (despite increasing the timeout).
I see NTR all time blocked high. No error messages on Cassandra logs either.'nodetool netstats' shows lot of small messages with high values in pending and completed. Not sure what the small messages imply. Any suggestions on how to debug this further.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a port issue, check if you have 9042 port open.

Run this to check open ports: 
`netstat -na|grep LISTEN`

you can have a look on this link for 
 more information. https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/secureFireWall.html

Comment: Thanks. The port is fine as some of the connections are in ESTABLISHED as well. Here is a count of connections in ESTABLISHED, FIN_WAIT, CLOSE_WAIT: 37, 121, 138